# Php, form, redirect and queries

Tags: php, html, forms

I feel like it's a common question but I didn't find a proper answer for it so I ask you ! ;)

Let's start with the form in classic *index.php* :

```
...
    <form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">
        <div style="color:white">Instructions</div>
        <input type="number" name="param" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="view" />
        <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="Solution" />

        <input type="????" name="instance_id" value="?????" />

        <input type="submit" value="Solutions Listing" id="button_solutions">
    </form>
...
```

The question here is the **last input** field before the submit button. The user is supposed to enter **param** in the first non-hidden input, and that should trigger a php function which determine the **instance_id** by picking into a database.

What I want to do is that when the user click on submit, it **redirect** through a link like

```
BASE_URL."?controller=Solution&action=view&param=toto&instance_id=value"
```

let's say my function in php which pick into the database is called toto(), toto returns instance_id. 
I know how to point to an url with GET parameters via the form, **but** *I don't know how to trigger the php function.*
I know how to determine instance_id via the param input **but** *I don't know how to create a redirection with GET parameters via a php function*

please any help would be considered 
Thanks

Comment: Am I correct in understand that you want the form action to be dynamic based on the form inputs?

Comment: This is can't be done alone with PHP, you need to use AJAX (client-side) request to your PHP that sends the param and then gets the response.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @amflare I tried something dynamic with jQuery but it didn't trigger the function , it just wrote the call into url

Comment: @Akam is AJAX the only way ? I'll have to read more doc so, just thought that I was missing something

Comment: AJAX is your best bet.

Comment: and @skrilled thank you now I have a terminology for this kind of frustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to see the instance_id on your client, your could create some kind of redirect page, which retrieves the instance_id from your database. This page could be the same as your destination page.

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">
    <div style="color:white">Instructions</div>
    <input type="number" name="param" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="view" />
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="Solution" />

    <input type="submit" value="Solutions Listing" id="button_solutions">
</form>
```

and in your php script

```
// instance_id not set
if (!isset($_GET['instance_id'])) {
    $args = $_GET;
    $param = $args['param'];

    // do something with param and save it to instance_id
    $instance_id = ...

    $args['instance_id'] = $instance_id;

    // create get query
    $query = http_build_query($args);

    $url = BASE_URL . '?' . $query;
    header('Location: ' . $url);
} else {
    // instance_id set - do something with it
    $instance_id = $_GET['instance_id'];
}
```

If you can't use this approach and have to show the result of your instance_id the same time, the user enters the param, you have to use an ajax request, which sends an request to the server to get the instance_id.

An JavaScript (using jQuery) to do this could look like this:

```
$('input[name="param"]').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: { param: $(this).val() },
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('input[name="instance_id"]').val(data);
    });
});
```

The php file get the `param` as GET value and should return the instance_id from your database.